# What does @synthesize variable = _variable really do? Is it very helpful?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I get that `@synthesize`-ing a variable automatically creates the accessor methods for the `@property` defined in my .h file and that using `= _variable` tells the compiler the name to use for my backing variable, but does it do anything else for me?
I have pretty much been assigning and reading from my class variables using something like

```
self.variableName = somethingElse
```

or

```
self.someLabel.text = self.someString
```

Could I instead (assuming all @synthesize statements are correct, etc.) do something like?

```
_variableName = somethingElse
```

Instead of using self.variable can I go around using _variable and not worry about it? Should I use `[_variable release]` in my `dealloc` or `[self.variable release]`?

I'm still confused on some of the why's of objective-c/cocoa/iOS development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@synthesize varible1` is equivalent to `@synthesize variable1 = variable1` -- It's saying that you're giving the instance variable and the property the same name.

When you say `@synthesize variable1 = variable2`, `variable1` is the name of the property and `variable2` is the name of the instance variable.

With the above `@synthesize` statement, if you say:

```
self.variable1 = something;
```

then, if the property has the "retain" attribute, the object `something` is retained (and any old object in variable1 is released).

But if you say:

```
variable2 = something;
```

Then no retains/releases occur.  Most likely this will result in a lost object bug.

As to the release in `dealloc`, you can say either

```
[self.variable1 release];
```

or

```
[variable2 release];
```

Though the latter is preferred.

You can also say:

```
self.variable1 = nil;
```

This will release the variable and nil it.

But note that the first two forms should *only* be used in `dealloc`.

Comment: So, if I have a synthesized variable, say `MyClass *aVariable` I would  still want to use `self.aVariable = something`, or `something = self.aVariable` when using it, correct? Does a `@property` of `retain` differ from `copy` in how I would want to reference it or vice versa?

Comment: If the property has the "assign" attribute (which is the default) and the "nonatomic" attribute (which is *not* the default) then there's no difference between referencing the property vs the instance variable.  Otherwise there's a difference on write and possibly (for atomic) on read.  It's kind of important to understand the differences due to the attributes.

Comment: And, of course, this whole discussion is mostly assuming a non-ARC environment.  When you use ARC there's a different (but similarly arcane) set of rules.

Comment: I'm glad you caught assign from my typo of retain.

Comment: In short: With `@property(nonatomic, retain)` and `@synthesize myVar = _myVar`, it is safe (is it acceptable?) to use `_myVar = something` and `something = _myVar`, but for most other `@property` combos `self.myVar` is how it needs to be referenced? So I'm not completely off base by just using self.myVar to get/set my variables?

Comment: Also, would it make sense to specify in the question that I'm not in an ARC environment?

Comment: With (nonatomic, retain) it is *not* "safe" to use `_myVar = something`.  This is because `something` will not be automatically retained, nor will any previous value in `_myVar` be automatically released.  If you were using (nonatomic, assign), on the other hand, it *would* be "safe" in virtually all circumstances (since by using "retain" you indicate you do not want automatic retain/release, and you presumably have assured that you don't need it.)

Comment: And, yes.  In general, when discussing storage management issues, you should specify whether you're using ARC or not.  Previously the assumption has been that you're not using ARC unless you say otherwise, but now there's enough ARC usage that it's becoming a bit of a muddle if you don't say one way or the other.

Comment: I appreciate the follow ups. I'm hoping to make it clear for anyone else who should stumble on this, because as I've read fragmented docs and posts across the web I never felt I was getting the full answer and felt as if I was writing my code defensively, without knowing the full reason of why.

Comment: It's confusing.  It brings to mind the sequence in [*Through the Looking-Glass*](http://www.gutenberg.org/dirs/1/12/12-h/12-h.htm), where Alice is talking to the Red Knight: 'No, you don't understand,' the Knight said, looking a little vexed. 'That's what the name is CALLED. The name really IS "THE AGED AGED MAN."'

Answer (score 1):

The reason to do it is this.

Say you are overriding an accessor in ARC.  You write it like so:

```
- (void) setMyValue:(NSString *)myValue
{
    _myValue = myValue;
}
```

If you had not done:

```
@synthesize myValue = _myValue;
```

You would have to re-name the argument coming in to not shadow your instance variable.

Also as the esteemed "Hot Licks" noted, if you leave the instance variable named `myValue` it's too easy to use it directly instead of the accessor, which means when you override that accessor it doesn't affect all the code it should.

Comment: Clarifying the last bit: With `@synthesize myValue;`, you can simply say `myValue`, and that will seem to work, but you'll be accessing the instance variable directly, not using the property's accessors. With `@synthesize myValue = _myValue;`, referring to `myValue` (absent any other declaration of a variable with that name) is invalid; you must use `_myValue` to access the instance variable, or `self.myValue` to access the property.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Thanks for the addition.